# A question about product representation of quantum Fourier transform

Tags: binary, quantum-computation

In the Nielsen and Chuang's *Quantum Computing and Quantum Information*, the last step of proving the product representation of quantum Fourier transform is
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\bigotimes_{l=1}^{n}
\left[
|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i j 2^{-l}}|1\rangle
\right]
=\frac{
\left(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_n}|1\rangle\right)
\left(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_{n-1}j_n}|1\rangle\right)\cdots 
\left(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_1 j_2\cdots j_n}|1\rangle\right)}{2^{n/2}}.
$$

I think there is a mistake.
For example, if $j=3=11_{2}$ and $l=1$, then
$$
|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{-1}}|1\rangle
\neq 
|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i \cdot 0.1_{2}}|1\rangle
$$
Do I misunderstand anything?

The same question has been asked on [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078595/quantum-fourier-transformation-product-representation), but it doesn't attract much attention and the answer is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is $e^{2\pi i m}=1$ if $m$ is a positive integer.
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\bigotimes_{l=1}^{n} \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi ij2^{-l}}|1\rangle\right]
&=& \bigotimes_{l=1}^{n} \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i\frac{j_1 2^{n-1}+j_2 2^{n-2}+\cdots +j_n 2^0}{2^{l}}}|1\rangle\right] \\
&=& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i\frac{j_1 2^{n-1}+j_2 2^{n-2}+\cdots +j_n 2^0}{2}}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i\frac{j_1 2^{n-1}+j_2 2^{n-2}+\cdots +j_n 2^0}{2^2}}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \cdots \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i\frac{j_1 2^{n-1}+j_2 2^{n-2}+\cdots +j_n 2^0}{2^n}}|1\rangle\right] \\
&=& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(m_1+\frac{j_n}{2})}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(m_2+\frac{j_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{j_n}{2^2})}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \cdots \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(\frac{j_1}{2}+\frac{j_2}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{j_n}{2^n})}|1\rangle\right]
\end{array}
$$

Since $e^{2\pi i m}=1$ if $m$ is a positive integer, we can omit them. So the previous expression is
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
&& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(\frac{j_n}{2})}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(\frac{j_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{j_n}{2^2})}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \cdots \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i(\frac{j_1}{2}+\frac{j_2}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{j_n}{2^n})}|1\rangle\right] \\
&=& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_n}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_{n-1} j_n}|1\rangle\right] \\
&+& \cdots \\
&+& \left[|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i 0.j_1 j_2 \cdots j_n}|1\rangle\right]
\end{array}
$$